# With Ansible how can I replace a variable with Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I need to replace a variable that has the extra argument passed to it via CLI.

```
./deploy.yml -e 'jira_ticket=REL-78'
```

I can't get it to strip out 'deploylist/REL-78' because I'm passing in 'jira_ticket' If i hardcode the varible ('REL-78') it works perfectly.

```
- name: Set fact
  set_fact: deploy_list"{{ item | replace('deploylist/{{ jira_ticket }}/', '')"
  with_items: ' {{ modules_to_deploy.value }}'
  register: deploy_list_result

ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/api)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/ariaapi)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/ariaquery)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/ariaserver)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/dashboardidp)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/oracle)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/uisp)
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=deploylist/REL-78/ui)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this... (I also added `=` and closing `}}`)

```
- name: Set fact
  set_fact: deploy_list="{{ item | replace('deploylist/'+jira_ticket+'/', '') }}"
  with_items: modules_to_deploy.value
  register: deploy_list_result
```

Note that you don't have to stringify an argument for `with_items`.

Comment: Thank you! I found an old thread suggesting the same thing. Took me a while!